# splitting an array without foreach

Tags: php

I have an array of items

```
 $arr1 = Array(266=>"foo",178=>"bar",3="foobar");
```

and then I have an of array of numbers like this

```
 $arr2 = Array(0 => 266, 1 => 178);
```

and so what I want to do is split array one into two arrays

where the values of $arr2 that match the index of $arr1 are moved to a new array so I am left with

```
 $arr1 = Array(3="foobar");

 $arr2= Array(266=>"foo",178=>"bar");
```

that said I know I could do this with a foreach loop but I wonder if this is a simpler and faster way to do this

something like array_diff would be could but I don't think that will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$arr1 = array(266=>"foo",178=>"bar",3=>"foobar");
$arr2 = array(0 => 266, 1 => 178);

$tmp = array_diff_key ($arr1, array_flip($arr2));
$arr2 = array_diff($arr1,$tmp);
$arr1 = $tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr2=array_interest($arr1,array_flip($arr2));
$arr1=array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: I think he might have meant array_intersect. Haven't tested, but it could well work :)

Comment: @Berry Langerak that nolonger gives me the error but it doesn't give the correct results

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array( 
    266 => "foo",
    178 => "bar",
    3 => "foobar"
);

$arr2 = array(
    0 => 266,
    1 => 178
);

$foo = array_filter( 
    array_flip( $arr1 ),
    function( $key ) use ( $arr2 ) {
        return in_array( $key, $arr2 );
    }
);

var_dump( array_flip( $foo ) );
```

The two array_flip's are there because array_filter will only take the value, not the key. Effectively, I'm not too sure whether or not this is more efficient than foreach though, you'd have to test.

Comment: does give the correct results for arr2 and then i guess I would need to use array_diff_assoc on arr1 and arr2 ?